# Execute a part of code based on user input without if statement in python

Tags: python, oop

I have a long list of functions that needs to be executed based on user input

I want a way to do this **without a long if else statement**

Thanks in advance this will save a lot of time

```
def function1(a,b):
    return a+b

def function2(a,b):
    return a-b
.
.
.
there a are many functions like this
.
.
.

class marks:
    def __init__(self,w,b):
        self.w=w
        self.b=b

    def execute(self,function):
        I WANT TO KNOW THIS PART

m=marks(50,30)

m.execute("function2") should perform function2 and print
m.execute("function45") should perform function45 and print
```

Comment: probably `getattr(object_instance, method_name)` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `locals()`

```
def execute(self, function):
    locals()[function]()
```

BUT you also need a way to pass arguments to those functions like

```
def execute(self, function, *args):
    locals()[function](*args)
```

More info here: [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)

Comment: what if the function  is in an imported module? say I'm trying to call numpy.add() , I'm getting a key error

Answer (score 2):

Set up a dictionary in the style `action = {'keyword1':function1,'keyword2':function2...}` then for user input `entry` you can check the input with `entry in action` and activate with `action[entry]()`.

Comment: Note that this allows multiple synonyms for a given action if desired, `{'key1':function1, 'key1alt':function1, 'key1alt2':function1, 'key2':function2...}` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [eval](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval) function:

```
names = {"function1": function1, "function2": function2 ...}
func = input('which function do you want to call')
print(eval(func, names))
```